# Humongous Handout formatted Word file created with PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2007

**What I'm doing**

I use **PowerPoint** to create lectures and I mail merge data for the speaker to read and speak about and so forth into the respective lectures.

I've been converting the lectures to `Handout` format by using the **PowerPoint** options of `publish` | `MS word handouts` and use **Word** mail merge features.

This method seems to retain the comments and notes and all are visible in the  slides in the handout format.

---

**My Issues**

- The exported handout in **Word** format remains as actual slides and
  retains links to the original `PPT` rather than being just an image.
- The file size gets very big so a `10 MB`  PowerPoint file grows to `212 MB` in `DOC` format and `88 MB` in `DOCX` format.

---

**Question**

- Is there any option to convert handouts exported from PowerPoint to Word as images?

***I cannot save them as png from PowerPoint since that will not include the comment data.***

Comment: Please give some more info and in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will solve it entirely, as I am not understanding exactly - but after you have imported it in to Word, can you print it as a PDF using Adobe Acrobat or a free tool such as [Bullzip PDF](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php).

You can then hand out this and it should look exactly the same but be a fraction of the file size.

Comment: This is a good, quick, and easy work around.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the ppt as images (PNG would be better) by using Save As.